# error streaming from two webcams in opencv

Tags: c, opencv, v4l2

I am trying to make a cheap stereo camera by reading from two usb webcams simultaneously. My code:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    char * window1_name = "Cam 1";
    char * window2_name = "Cam 2";
    CvCapture* capture1 = cvCaptureFromCAM( 1 );
    CvCapture* capture2 = cvCaptureFromCAM( 2 );
    namedWindow(window1_name, CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );
    namedWindow(window2_name, CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );


    while ( 1 ) {
      // Get one frame                                                                                                                          
      IplImage* cam1_frame = cvQueryFrame( capture1);
      IplImage* cam2_frame = cvQueryFrame( capture2 );
      usleep(100000);
      cvShowImage( window1_name, cam1_frame );
      cvShowImage( window2_name, cam2_frame );                                                                                                                                                                                                      
      if ( (cvWaitKey(10) & 255) == 27 ) break;
    }                                                                                       
    cvReleaseCapture( &capture1 );
    cvReleaseCapture( &capture2 );
}
```

I am getting the following output.

```
VIDIOC_QUERYMENU: Invalid argument
VIDIOC_QUERYMENU: Invalid argument
VIDIOC_QUERYMENU: Invalid argument
VIDIOC_QUERYMENU: Invalid argument
VIDIOC_QUERYMENU: Invalid argument
VIDIOC_QUERYMENU: Invalid argument
VIDIOC_QUERYMENU: Invalid argument
libv4l2: error setting pixformat: Device or resource busy
HIGHGUI ERROR: libv4l unable to ioctl S_FMT
libv4l2: error setting pixformat: Device or resource busy
libv4l1: error setting pixformat: Device or resource busy
HIGHGUI ERROR: libv4l unable to ioctl VIDIOCSPICT
```

My camera's are both Logitech c210 and I am on Ubuntu 12.10. When I try to stream from just one camera I am able to see the feeds from each camera. One camera is cvCaptureFromCAM(1) and the other is cvCaptureFromCAM(2), but it won't work at the same time. I tried compiling the latest v4l which I believe is what the camera's use. Still nothing.

Edit:

Turns out I my USB bus only supported 900 MB/s and each camera was taking 480 MB/s at the default resolution of 640x480. I used v4l2-ctl program to change the default resolution before executing the program and it worked at the lower resolution.

```
v4l2-ctl -d /dev/video1 --set-fmt-video=width=320,height=240,pixelformat=YUYV
v4l2-ctl -d /dev/video2 --set-fmt-video=width=320,height=240,pixelformat=YUYV
./my_program
```

Comment: Have you tried with cvCaptureFromCAM(0) and cvCaptureFromCAM(1). Because the default camera number is 0. So give a try.

Answer (score 0):

There might be chance you might have missed some header files. The below code runs perfectly in my machine. although am using windows. I dont have a UBUNTU machine to test. Any how try the below code.

Opencv takes "0" as default camera. So make it 0 and 1.

```
#include "opencv2/objdetect/objdetect.hpp"
     #include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
     #include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"
    #include "opencv2/contrib/contrib.hpp"

    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <iostream>
    #include <string>
    #include <fstream>
    #include <sstream>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <time.h>
    int main(int argc, const char** argv)
    {
        const char * window1_name = "Cam 1";
        const char * window2_name = "Cam 2";
        CvCapture* capture1 = cvCaptureFromCAM( 0 );
        CvCapture* capture2 = cvCaptureFromCAM( 1 );
        namedWindow(window1_name, CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );
        namedWindow(window2_name, CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );


        while ( 1 ) {
          // Get one frame                                                                                                                          
          IplImage* cam1_frame = cvQueryFrame( capture1);
          IplImage* cam2_frame = cvQueryFrame( capture2 );
    //      sleep(100000);
          cvShowImage( window1_name, cam1_frame );
          cvShowImage( window2_name, cam2_frame );                                                                                                                                                                                                      
          if ( (cvWaitKey(10) & 255) == 27 ) break;
        }                                                                                       
        cvReleaseCapture( &capture1 );
        cvReleaseCapture( &capture2 );
    }
```

Comment: My video0 was the laptops built-in and my code was trying to access to other cameras.